# nodejs getting db delayed result only works with console.log

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, closures

I'm aware of the event-driven/non-blocking stuff of node and I've been using it for about 2 years...
recently I came through this problem I can't solve it even forcing a closure...

I'm asking database for a simple result: 'SELECT 1+1 as theResult'

```
(...)  // previous code

var dbRows1 = {};  // empty object to hold rows
var dbRows2 = {};  // idem

var mysql = require( 'mysql' );
var db = mysql.createConnection( dbInfo );  // dbInfo has connction data

var test = function( a ) { dbRows2 = a };

db.connect( 
    function( err ) 
        { 
        if (err) throw err.stack; 
        console.log( 'TID ->', db.threadId) 
        });

db.query ( 
    'SELECT 1+1 AS XXX',
    function( err, rows, fields ) 
            {
            console.log( 'rows ->', rows );  // works ok
            dbRows1 = rows;  // don't work because rows is still empty
            test( rows );  // !!!should work but dbRows2 is empty at program end!!!

            });

(...) // more code

console.log( dbRows2 );
```

the last line prints a empty object for dbRows2 ( { } )...
Any ideas why console.log() works and my test() function do not work...

Comment: Where are you checking dbRows2 'at program end'?  Because the query is asynchronous, program end would have to wait for that query to complete before checking the results of the assignment made in test.

Comment: the check is at program end... 
I'll edit the example to add it...

Answer (score 0):

Your test function is working, the problem is that, at the time your last `console.log` statement executes, the test function hasn't been executed yet.  This is because both `.connect` and `.query` are asynchronous.

The program flow looks something like this:

- connect is called and queued
- query is called and queued
- console.log(dbRows2) is called
- (time passes...)
- connect succeeds and calls back
- (time passes...)
- query succeeds and calls back
- test is called assigning rows to dbRows2

You can verify this behavior yourself by placing some strategic logging in your code before each action and inside of the callbacks.  If you were to do that you would see something like this in your console:

```
about to call connect
about to call query
logging dbRows2
connect succeeded
query succeeded
about to call test
```

Without knowing the exact structure of your code, the following provides a rough example of how you might structure your logic to ensure the code that depends on the query completing is only invoked after the query completes:

```
db.query ( 
    'SELECT 1+1 AS XXX',
    function( err, rows, fields ) 
            {
            console.log( 'rows ->', rows );  // works ok
            dbRows1 = rows;  // don't work because rows is still empty
            test( rows );  // !!!should work but dbRows2 is empty at program end!!!

            // Call doStuffThatDependsOnQuery here
            doStuffThatDependsOnQuery();
            });

(...) // more code that doesn't depend on db.query(...)

function doStuffThatDependsOnQuery() {
    console.log( dbRows2 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,,, but shouldn't the test() function ( that sets dbRows2 ) be queued and 'satisfied' before program end... ?how can we solve this... (without loading any extra libraries)

Comment: I'd assumed when you said "the check is at program end..." that you meant as the last statement in the module, not when all the rest of the logic finished executing.  Without knowing exactly how your code in structured, it is hard to give a definitive answer but the basic solution is to either put or call the logic that depends on the query being complete within the query callback.  I will add an example.